# Are there alternatives to the ranger cabins in Algonquin Park?

Tags: accommodation, canada, camping, ontario

Had stumbled upon the [ranger cabins](http://www.algonquinpark.on.ca/visit/camping/ranger-cabins.php) that Algonquin Park rents out during the season, but after doing some research, found that they're booked solid for the summer (and from what I'm told you have to book the day that they're available they're that popular). So was wondering if anyone knew of anything similar in the area that existed at all? The only options i found through the parks are at least a few hours (if not more) drive from Algonquin, which had a lot of the items that we wanted to check out.

Comment: Alternative in what way? Do you want to still be inside the park to be close to something? Or do you still want the walls and roof and you wouldn't mind being at the edge of the park? Are you planning to hike or canoe there?

Comment: Well a perfect setup would be to be close to the eastern enterence due to some events going on there that driving four horus too would be a bit of an annoyance. But mainly yes the walls/roof but still able to drive too. Our hiking/canoeing skills are entry level to put it mildly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Camping is always an option and is easy enough, but it may not be what you consider "similar" to roofed accommodation.

Other than the ranger cabins your other option appears to be one of the three lodges in the park:

- [Arowhon Pines Resort](http://www.algonquinpark.on.ca/visit/park_lodges_outfitters/arowhon-pines-lodge.php)
- [Bartlett Lodge](http://www.algonquinpark.on.ca/visit/park_lodges_outfitters/bartlett-lodge.php)
- [Killarney Lodge](http://www.algonquinpark.on.ca/visit/park_lodges_outfitters/killarney-lodge.php)

All three are inside the park, just off Highway 60.

Other than that, [Tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g319818-Algonquin_Park_Ontario-Hotels.html) has a number of external accommodation options within 20 or so miles of the park boundaries.

Answer (score 4):

I own Red Deer Log Cabins, in Madawaska.  The location is about a 20 minute drive from the east gate on highway 60.  On a quiet sideroad, and a beautiful west facing waterfront with a sand beach, my place is often used as an affordable base camp for those wanting to spend time in Algonquin Park.  Please check [my site](http://www.reddeercabin.ca).  You can find reviews on TripAdvisor.

I don't know what map you used, Karlson, but it is much closer than 50 km to the east gate on hwy 60 from here.  I think it is 28 km, and takes about 20 minutes to reach the east gate driving at the speed limit of 80 km/hour.

Comment: Thanks, Sandra, for meeting the criteria stack exchange uses for posts with external links that some people might think are spam: you've identified your association to the link, made it clear what is on the other end of the link, and provided enough information in this answer that people don't even have to click the link. Your answer is also a direct answer to the question that was asked, rather than a tack-on to something unrelated just to promote yourself.  Welcome to the site and I hope you have other answers to provide that are not just about your cabins specifically.

Comment: It's also helpful to fill in your profile with more information about whatever organization or website you are affiliated with.

Comment: Sandra your cabins are about 50km from the park if the map doesn't lie.

Comment: Hi Kate, can't say I will be answering many other questions until the 2013 tourist season is over.  I have a 6 month work shift, part of which is trying to make sure people can find my place.  I do intend to be back, in my free time, during the winter.

Comment: Turns out I got curious and went for a cruise on the site this evening.  So I am back before the winter.  Probably be back again, now that I found a second question to contribute to.  Haven't had much chance to travel since I became a proprietor...

Comment: I also filled in my profile, though I thought I identified myself clearly in my post.  My site is also quite clear and 100% honest.  I made it myself.  If you go there, you can even find out my phone number and physical address, identifying characteristics that are not required in the profile.